# Give a tight big-oh run-time analysis for this code fragment

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
public static long F (int N) {
    if ( N == 1 ) return 1;

    return F(N - F(N-1));
}
```

Now I thought the inside F(N-1) will execute N times for each of the F( N - F(N-1)) and so it will be N<sup>2</sup> but that doesn't seem to be the answer.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What is the actual answer? I'm honestly asking because I'm still learning about Big-O analysis lol.

Comment: O(N) since it could be expressed as a loop 1...N

Comment: @n8wrl I'm not sure that's correct. I'm getting a tight bound of Theta(2^n). Can you elaborate on why it should be O(N)?

Comment: I would call this evaluating a constant function in exponential time. :-) Nice.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Because I'm an idiot who can't read a simple expression. Forget everything I said :(

Comment: This was a really cool problem! Where is it from?

Comment: @templatetypedef My professor :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To figure this one out, let's imagine rewriting this code in an equivalent way:

```
public static int F (int N) {
    if ( N == 1 ) return 1;
    int k = F(N - 1);
    return F(N - k);
}
```

All I've done here is pull out the inner call to `F(N - 1)` and move it to the top-level so that we can more clearly see that this code makes two calls to `F` and that the second call is to a subproblem that depends on the first call.

To determine the runtime here, we'll need to figure out what k is so we can see what kind of recursive call we're making. Interesting, it turns out that F(N) = 1 for all N. You can spot this pattern here:

- F(1) = 1.
- F(2) = F(2 - F(1)) = F(2 - 1) = F(1) = 1
- F(3) = F(3 - F(2)) = F(3 - 1) = F(2) = 1
- F(4) = F(4 - F(3)) = F(4 - 1) = F(3) = 1

It's a great exercise to prove this by induction.

So this means that the call to F(N - k) will call F(N - 1). This means that the code is functionally equivalent to

```
public static int F (int N) {
    if ( N == 1 ) return 1;
    int k = F(N - 1);
    return F(N - 1);
}
```

This has recurrence relation

- F(1) = 1
- F(n) = 2F(n-1) + 1

Which solves F(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1. (Again, you can formally prove this by induction if you'd like). Therefore, the complexity is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).

To validate this, here's a (really hacky) C script that calls the function on a number of different inputs, reporting the returned value and the number of calls made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Slightly modified version of F that tracks the number of calls made          
 * using the second out parameter.                                              
 */
static int F (int N, int* numCalls) {
  /* Track the number of calls. */
  (*numCalls)++;

  if ( N == 1 ) return 1;
  return F (N - F (N-1, numCalls), numCalls);
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    int numCalls = 0;
    int result = F(i, &numCalls);
    printf("F(%d) = %d, making %d calls.\n", i, result, numCalls);
  }
}
```

The output is

```
F(1) = 1, making 1 calls.
F(2) = 1, making 3 calls.
F(3) = 1, making 7 calls.
F(4) = 1, making 15 calls.
F(5) = 1, making 31 calls.
F(6) = 1, making 63 calls.
F(7) = 1, making 127 calls.
F(8) = 1, making 255 calls.
F(9) = 1, making 511 calls.
```

Notice that evaluating F(i) always takes 2<sup>i</sup> - 1 calls (just as the theory predicted!) and always returns 1, empirically validating the mathematical analysis.

Comment: I am not really adding anything here, but just want to point out that this is the same idea as the more commonly known Big-O of the naive Fibonacci implementation.

Comment: @baruch It's actually not quite the same. The naive Fibonacci implementation has the recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + 1, which solves to Theta(phi^n), where phi is the golden ratio ((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2). It's still exponential, but not the same.

Comment: I'm confused by your "equivalent function" which does indeed call itself twice while the original function only calls itself once. Passing N to the original function calls that function N-1 times. That seems like O(N)

Comment: @n8wrl The original function does call itself twice - the call `F(N - F(N-1))` makes two calls to `F`: one for `F(N-1)` inside the expression, and one for `F(N - F(N-1))` on the outside of the expression.